# derive major mode but do not derive mode hooks

Tags: major-mode

I am trying to reuse lots of things that are built in `c-mode` for technically another c-like language, including syntactical highlighting and stuff like that.

However, `c-mode` in my settings are customized using mode hooks. Specifically, I have enabled following two lines in my `c-mode-hook`:

```
  (semantic-mode t)
  (semantic-idle-summary-mode t)
  (semantic-stickyfunc-mode t)
```

But this is breaking the major mode derived from `c-mode`, because `semantic-mode` has no idea how to parse the source file in another c-like language. Is there a way to derive a major mode from an existing one without running the hooks for the parent?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268882/derive-from-lisp-mode-ignoring-its-hooks

Comment: that is very sad according to that answer.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, e.g., to request an enhancement along the lines @Stefan sugggested in his answer - for `c-mode`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [duplicate Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268882/derive-from-lisp-mode-ignoring-its-hooks), you can't sensibly do what you're asking.

However, it's easy enough to modify your custom hook function to prevent the unwanted code from running for your derived mode by testing `major-mode` (which you would typically do via `derived-mode-p` in order to also catch derivatives of the derivative, etc...).

```
(unless (derived-mode-p 'YOUR-MODE)
  (semantic-mode t)
  (semantic-idle-summary-mode t)
  (semantic-stickyfunc-mode t))
```